# Which npm/bin folder(s) should be in the PATH ? ( OS X 10.8.2 / npm installed with homebrew )

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

Upgrading **node** by using **homebrew**

```
==> Downloading http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.21/node-v0.8.21.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.8.21
==> make install
```

I'm noticed this

```
==> Caveats
Homebrew installed npm.
We recommend prepending the following path to your PATH environment
variable to have npm-installed binaries picked up:
  /usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

In the `$PATH` I had already: `/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/scripted/bin`
Should I add `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` too?

Please note that `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` only contains two subfolder: `scr` and  `scripted` that are also in `/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/scripted/bin` so what's the *difference in the purpose* of these two folders?

**EDIT** 
`/usr/local/share/npm/bin` only contains two symlinks ( not subfolders )

Comment: In `/etc/environment` I added `NODE_PATH`. Refer to `node --help` then `Environment variables` bottom section where `NODE_PATH` is listed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you are upgrading from old version fo node? I'm using node from homebrew repository since 0.8.17 and i don't have any subfolders in my `/usr/local/share/npm/bin`. It contains only simlinks to executable scripts of globally installed modules (in `/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules`). So, i have `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` in my $PATH and it works fine.
If you are upgrading from old version of `node` and `npm`, try to reinstall your globally installed modules before changing your $PATH.

Comment: your answer reminded me I installed [scripted](https://github.com/scripted-editor/scripted/) and to make it work I added /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/scripted/bin but now this should no longer be useful thanks to the simlink ( not subfolders, I edited my question ). Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and run command:

```
$ npm bin
```

Add line in **.zshrc** / **.bashrc** / **.profile**

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/USERNAME/node_modules/.bin"
```

Comment: Note that in NPM v9: _"`npm bin` has been removed (use npx or npm exec to execute binaries)"_ https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.0.0