# npm installing executable in usr/local/share/npm/bin rather than usr/local/bin

Tags: node.js, npm

For example I tried installing npm serve globally

```
$ npm install -g serve
```

but after seemingly successfully installing it, I was unable to run the serve executable.  Seems like the command just could not be found.  Turns out the exe serve file was located in:

```
usr/local/share/npm/bin
```

rather than in what I thought should be (where all the other executable files are):

```
usr/local/bin
```

Any idea why I can't seem to get this to work?

Comment: Seems to be a common issue with users installing with homebrew. Some useful resources can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170773/which-npm-bin-folders-should-be-in-the-path-os-x-10-8-2-npm-installed-wi), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803978/npm-global-path-prefix) and [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/21627).

Comment: @prattsj: +1 for links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6948567/1995977), create/edit `~/.npmrc` to include:

```sh
prefix = /usr/local/bin
```